# Map specific parent td ID based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble getting this code to report EACH machine name that has a child td with a class of 'up_avail'.  This code simply replies two times wtih the same machine name, rather than grabbing the two machine name which is intended.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<table border=1>
   <th>Machine Name</th><th>Result</th><th>Status</th>
   <tr>
     <td class="tdresult" id="WN-MN161FY0X066">WN-MN161FY0X066</td>
     <td>Found</td>
     <td class='up_avail'>New</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="tdresult" id="WD-ORA60YY1U015">WD-ORA60YY1U015</td>
     <td>Found</td>
     <td class='up_success'>Complete</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="tdresult" id="WD-ORA60YY1U030">WD-ORA60YY1U030</td>
     <td>Found</td>
     <td class='up_avail'>New</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<div id="set_status" class=button>Check</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#set_status').click(function() {
  var arrayOfIds = $.map($(".up_avail"), function() {
     return $('.up_avail').parent().parent().parent().find('.tdresult').attr("id");
  });
  alert(arrayOfIds);
});
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ge0yn8uc/7/

Comment: With `$('.up_avail').parent()...` inside the function, you select the parents of _all_ of those elements each time. And why are you going up so many parent levels ...? *One* parent up takes you to the table row, and inside that you want to find the `.tdresult` https://jsfiddle.net/ge0yn8uc/13/

Comment: If I'm being honest, it's the first code that I threw down and didn't think of it much.  Figured it would be up a parent for every TD.

Comment: Oh and thanks to all the downvotes without providing an explanation as to why it was downvoted.  Really helps developers learn what they are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either loop through using `.each` or use map on the up_avail classes and return the IDs that way.

```js
$('#set_status').click(function() {
   var arrayOfIds = $(".up_avail").map(function() { return $(this).parent().find('.tdresult').attr('id'); }).get();
   
   alert(arrayOfIds);
 });
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WN-MN161FY0X066">WN-MN161FY0X066</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_avail'>New</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WD-ORA60YY1U015">WD-ORA60YY1U015</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_success'>Complete</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WD-ORA60YY1U030">WD-ORA60YY1U030</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_avail'>New</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="set_status" class=button>Check</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to simply use `.siblings('.tdresult')` to map out all of the desired elements. From here, you can simply loop over the elements in question:

```js
$('#set_status').click(function() {
  var arrayOfIds = $.map($(".up_avail"), function() {
    return $('.up_avail').siblings('.tdresult');
  });

  $.each(arrayOfIds, function(index, value) {
    console.log(arrayOfIds[0][index].id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <th>Machine Name</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WN-MN161FY0X066">WN-MN161FY0X066</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_avail'>New</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WD-ORA60YY1U015">WD-ORA60YY1U015</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_success'>Complete</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WD-ORA60YY1U030">WD-ORA60YY1U030</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_avail'>New</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="set_status" class=button>Check</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way, by using jQ's `.siblings()`, `.get()` and JS's `.map()`

```js
$('#set_status').click(function() {

   var arrayOfIds = $(".up_avail").siblings(".tdresult").get().map(function(el) {
      return el.id;
   });
   
   alert(arrayOfIds);

 });
```

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WN-MN161FY0X066">WN-MN161FY0X066</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_avail'>New</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WD-ORA60YY1U015">WD-ORA60YY1U015</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_success'>Complete</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdresult" id="WD-ORA60YY1U030">WD-ORA60YY1U030</td>
    <td>Found</td>
    <td class='up_avail'>New</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="set_status" class="button">Check</button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or by using ES6 flavor, taking advantage of *arrow function* and *implicit return*:

```
$('#set_status').click(function() {

  var arrayOfIds = $(".up_avail").siblings(".tdresult").get().map(el => el.id);

  alert(arrayOfIds);

});
```